# Oxygen - Advanced Custom Fields Repeater sub-fields - link fields

Tags: arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

WordPress Repeater link fields: For testing purposes I have defined one link as an Array and the second link as URL. When adding the repeater to a template the output of one link is an Array and the other link is displayed as URL instead of the actual "link text". The link also doesn't open link in new tab as defined.

What's wrong with this setup? See attachments

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is your code? How are you outputting the link? If you set a link as an array without actually parsing the array, you won't get any output. If you set the link as just returning the link, you need to code that as well.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I am using Oxygen builder with a Repeater. It allows me to pull images, text ect. through the repeater element - however, the links are not working. I assume that you are referring to the PHP code to get Link Arrays?

Comment: Regarding the code you mentioned. This code doesn't work - maybe you can clarify. The link is supposed to be a sub-field (I guess). Sorry, amateur talking here...

<?php
$link = get_field('link');
?>
<a
role=“link” class=“txt-link”
href=“<?php echo $link['url']; ?>”
target =“<?php echo $link['target']; ?>”
<?php echo $link['title']; ?>
</a>

Comment: Do `echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field('tutorials'), TRUE ) . '</pre>';` in your code and paste that into your question. Also, move your PHP code to your question, it's relevant and screenshots are not enough.

Comment: To clarify, the repeater is already implemented correctly. The only missing piece is the link. Also, I tried out your code but it didn't work. Of course chances are great that I have added your code snippet wrongly - see below. (Will update my original question as soon my problem has been resolved. Thanks! 

<?php
$link = get_field('link');
?>
<a
role=“link” class=“txt-link”
href=“<?php echo $link['url']; ?>”
target =“<?php echo $link['target']; ?>”
<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r( get_field('tutorials'), TRUE ) . '</pre>';?>
<?php echo $link['title']; ?>
</a>

Comment: Please update your question now with the relevant code, not after it's been resolved - this will greatly improve other people being able to help. Are you using this data on a page, a post, a custom post type? All of this information is important to get help. What template is this code on?

Comment: Yes, will update my question in detail. Just waiting for Oxygen support to get back to me with answers.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution to the problem described above:

It is important to know that my issue with ACF and Repeater is related to the Wordpress Oxygen builder.

In order to get get link fields with target blank you need to do the following:

- CPT UI > create post type (set has Archive = true)
- Custom Fields > Add field type Repeater, add sub-fields = field type set to text
- Posts > Add Rows with link custom fields
- Create Template > Add repeater to page, add text link module, set data to appropriate Field Name
- Define link target: Add JS code block and add the following code

  jQuery('a').each(function() {
     var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
     if (!a.test(this.href)) {
        jQuery(this).attr("target","_blank");
     }
  });